# angularjs resource post with body

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

i am new to angularjs and am trying to do post with resource with body to exist api
when i send the post with body on postman it works fine do login and get token back

the api works fine 
how can i do that on angularjs

there is my code
this is the api

```
[Route("v1/token")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(LoginViewModel viewModel)
        {}
```

my resource factory

```
app.factory('getToken', function ($resource, $q) {

        return function (email, password) {
            console.log(email);
            console.log(password);
            return $resource('http://localhost:9303/v1/token', {}, {
                login: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/jsonp;'
                    },
                    body: {
                        Email: email,
                        Password: password
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

and this is my login function

```
loginService.login = function (username, password) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (username === 'erez' && password === 'pass') {
            var src = getToken('email','password').login(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
            console.log(src);
            deferred.resolve(src);
        }
        else {
            deferred.reject({ message: 'Unauthorized user' });
        }

        return deferred.promise;

    }
```

i get that error

```
POST http://localhost:9303/v1/token (anonymous function) @ angular.js:11442r @ angular.js:11235g @ angular.js:10945(anonymous function) @ angular.js:15552m.$eval @ angular.js:16820m.$digest @ angular.js:16636m.$apply @ angular.js:16928(anonymous function) @ angular.js:24551n.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js:3
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9303/v1/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:53647' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

when i debig the api when i get to the api the viewModel is null
why its null
he dont get my body

i have tried to replace body with params but same

thanks for the helpers

Comment: Well,  your problem is this **"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present..."**. It''s your server rejecting the request because comes from a location it doesn't know. What is needed is a alteration on server to allow requests from other sources. You should do some reading about it

Comment: so how does it work with postman with the same header?

Comment: Chrome packaged apps can have cross domain permissions. When you install Postman it promts you that this app will access any domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting form one domain to another domain e.g. from www.xyz.com to www.abc.com. In your case you are requesting to 'localhost:9303/v1/token' from Origin 'localhost:53647'.

For debugging purpose you can use Allow-Control-Allow-Origin plugin for google chrome and other browsers, otherwise you need to configure and allow localhost:9303/ to accept requests from other domain.

Comment: but when i debug the post api its catching the post req but the viewmodel is empty

Comment: you need to call the login function in order to send the viewModel to your API.

Comment: Please make following changes in your code and there you are... :)

Comment: return function () {
            
            return $resource('http://localhost:9303/v1/token', {}, {
                login: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/jsonp;'
                    }
                }
            });
            //and change where you call this service
            var src = getToken.login({Model Body here}).$promise().then(function(result){

                    console.log(result);
            });

Answer (score 1):

well i want to share my solution to this question
after lots of researches i figured that when you try to post to web api you have to be at the same domain its typical cross domain issue

first you need to install on package menage console

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

and if you have in your web.config should remove that

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol
```

and add this on the WebApiconfig

```
config.EnableCors();
```

and need to add this line to the post method on the web api

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

hope it will help someone
Regards